# If equation not working correctly in array formula

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making a waterfall commission structure and I have already figured out the equations for computing from one Input. I have also Added the equations together to do the equation in one line. However, I am currently having an issue when putting it in an array.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(($E$2:$E = ""),"",IF(($E$2:$E >='Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2), IF((('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$3 * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4) <= ($E$2:$E * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4)), ('Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$3 * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4), $E$2:$E*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4 ) , IF((0 >=($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2) * 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4),0,(($E$2:$E - 'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$I$2)*'Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$4)))))
```

Same Equations

```
=If($G$6 >=J2, IF(((J3*J4) <= $G$6*J4),(J3*J4),$G$6*J4),IF(0>=(($G$6-I2) *J4),0,($G$6-I2) *J4))

j1 | B2 , 
j2 | $100,000.00 , 
j3 | 50000 , 
j4 | 3.00%, 
j5 | $1,500.00,
J6 | result
```

This equation needs to return values based on revenue at a max of `100k`
It should return `0` for all values `50k` and under
the min return should be `0`
and max return `1500`
and values `100000` and under should be `1500 or (revenue - 50000 [i2]) *j4 (3%)`

the issue I am having is the when under `50k` it is returning `$300` vs `$0`
I am not sure where this additional `300` is coming from.

Results

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfj8D.png]

All help is appreciated!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: I am finding that the issue actually is in the first condition. IF(($E$2:$E >='Water Fall Commission Scale '!$J$2) (e2 = 10000) (j2 = 100000) this expression is returning true when it should return false. if you replace e2;e with 10000, the correct result is calculated ( this is why the equation is returning $300 when it should return 0. The actual result of the equation is (-1200), which would result in 0, not 300. How do I debug the expression?

Comment: Hi there @BlaisWalker! I don't fully grasp the contents of your last comment. If it includes new important information for this question, could you please update the question to include this information?